# stm32 FreeRTOS Interrupt cannot run smooth as i think

Tags: synchronization, embedded, task, interrupt, freertos

I have two tasks, T1 and T2. I want to switch between these two by invoking an ISR, yet, T1 and T2 both have their private `vTaskDelay`. How to let them run smoother when delay is in the code?

```c
void T1(void){

    while(1){
         
         if (tsk == 1) {

///          doSth
             vTaskDelay(2000) // 2seconds
//           doSth
         }
    }
}
void T2(void){

    while(1){
         
         if (tsk == 2) {

///          doSth
             vTaskDelay(1000) // 1seconds
//           doSth
         }
    }
}

void ISR(){
  if (READGPIO){
   // change tsk between 1 and 2
   
}
}
```

I tried spliting `vTaskDelay` into small pieces like this

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                vTaskDelay(10);
                if (tsk == 1) break;;
            }
```

however, it doesnot help with the smoothness i except

Comment: vTaskDelay means delay no matter what happens.  wait until an interrupt is different from delay.  You need to send an event in the interrupt and make the task wait for an event.  Try google for "freertos send event from interrupt".

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean by "smooth" that is a irrevocably non-technical term.  The tasks either schedule as you wish or they don't.  It is almost certainly an X-Y problem, and a delay of any kind is not what you need.  You have elided the code far too much with only a comment hinting at how the interrupt might be triggering the task.  It seems you are probably trying to manage the scheduling that is the job of the RTOS scheduler.  Better to describe your scheduling requirements and ask for a solution than to ask how to fix your clearly flawed solution.

Comment: As @gulpr has already stated, it would be very instructive if you have a look at the task notification API. Using task delay is usually not a good practice, unless you really have to keep a task in pending state. Designing an event based architecture makes your FW smoother. It also helps you on saving a lot of CPU time. If you try to synchronize several tasks (let say 10 just to give a number) by keeping them in pending state, it is more likely that the delays start causing problems due to the preemption especially when you use data coming from several busses inside the tasks bodies.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you learned a bit more about inter-task communication primitives before starting programming using RTOS.

Use for example [task notifications](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notification-API.html) and give the notification to the particular task from the ISR.

Answer (score 0):

```c
void LED_T2( void ){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for(;;){
        if (currentTask == 1) {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET );
            vTaskDelay(1000);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET );
             

        }
    vTaskDelay(1000);// outside of if ...
    }
}
// after
void LED_T2( void ){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for(;;){
        if (currentTask == 1) {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET );
            vTaskDelay(1000);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET );
            vTaskDelay(1000);

        }
    
    }
}
```

I fixed the code that bugs me... It seems like I need to study harder on the behavior of interrupt...

Anyways, thanks for ya'alls' replies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).